# How do I go about traveling with DNA extract samples?

Tags: dna

I am traveling from Fairbanks, Alaska to Vienna, Austria in six weeks and need to bring 10 very small (~50 ul) samples of extracted arctic ground squirrel DNA with me.

I need to travel with these on dry ice in a little carry-on cooler.

Has anyone flown with DNA samples? Any advice on how to go about it? Questions to ask customs?

Comment: I think it could also be asked at **[Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)** for a better answer.

Comment: Dry ice is classified as "dangerous goods" in most countries, probably because it can explode! It depends on the airline how much or if you can carry it with you. As an example, Swiss Air allows up to 2.5 kg per person with prior registration. See [this question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/any-issues-getting-ftdna-sample-vials-through-airport-customs) for carrying DNA. As these regulations vary by country and airline, you'd probably be better off if you contact your airline before going to the airport.